# Why this keyof doesn't infer correctly?

Tags: typescript

I've code like this ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBhEBbADjAvDADwAqMiAHmmACYQwDeAUDDFiDQJYBmni8EAFytmrVgG0A1ogCew6PE5gA5gF15URSoDcLGAF9drGom7IArgBsoAWQ5CY0mSG4wS4gETsuvfhA%20quvpMAHwAFKBYwiQAlAQhcNi6TEygkLDQMpaIBHBIqBjYOGGibBw8fALCpawARpbmiMIA5PWNzQA0eqxINC29zXr6XcamFtZ2dP2INM0wAPTzifBIwFAAdDAmZla29jBQMjg5nPTNAzAAPjCtDYiD%20jHaQA)):

```
const createComp = <T extends {
  modifiers:  {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  defaultMods: keyof T["modifiers"];
}
>(com: T) => com;

const style = createComp({
  modifiers: {
    blue: 'blue',
    red: 'red'
  },
  defaultMods: 'red' // correct. defaultMods type is 'blue' | 'red'
});
```

It infer `defaultMods` type to `'blue' | 'red'` as I expected.

But when I try to extract the `extends` type to `Component` type, like this ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=18&pln=6&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwoF4oG8BQUUCcAJgJYBm5EATgM4BcRBRRA2gNYQjP3C1yKAOYBdPgKHCA3ISgBfWUVIRKAQwCuAG2ABZMkyjcQcSrETI0GdgCISFanXo3Rs%20fg8BjVPyifaEGrAEPBI2FAAPAAqUBAAHsEopPTmSKjowAB8ABTeCMxRAJTYmX6Isl4%20mPwgWtA4-oHBoWDZrMRkVDQMzO1EAEZaGhDMAOSDw6MANHJEAaRj86Ny8jPKqpo6%20sljo1AA9PtQ5NUAFnDapFD90ONDEHsAPlCjS-jyhdJAA)):

```
type Component = {
  modifiers:  {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  defaultMods: keyof Component["modifiers"];
}

const createComp = <T extends Component>(com: T) => com;

const style = createComp({
  modifiers: {
    blue: 'blue',
    red: 'red'
  },
  defaultMods: '' // defaultMods type is string
});
```

It doesn't return `defaultMods` type as `'blue' | 'red'`. Did I miss something?

Comment: You are using `keyof Component` which in not infered type but static type definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyof Component["modifiers"]` always resolves to `string`. You will need an extra type parameter to `Component` to represent the modifiers, and infer that in your function:

```
type Component<TModifiers extends Record<string, string>> = {
  modifiers: TModifiers;
  defaultMods: keyof TModifiers;
}


const createComp = <TModifiers extends Record<string, string>>(com: Component<TModifiers>) => com;


const style = createComp({
  modifiers: {
    blue: 'blue',
    red: 'red'
  },
  defaultMods: '' // it should be 'blue' | 'red'
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AVAsnAEwEsAzIiAJwGcoIAPYdAmgJQgGM4KDMrgKiKAOYAaKHwHCAfFKgBeKAG8AUFCgJCpctQBcUPJrKUqAblVQCEEgEMArgBtg+ZnoDWEEHBL7nW42YBfZWDOFD4odgoIa0Z4JHkoHF8jaloGJlYOLh4JQVFxfjyZAApOBD045DQMJMNtKikASnlZMrMQ1HC+EHtoBUjo2MQwYpU1DWIUqj0xtSgAI3tbCD0AckXl1ZFzNSiCNb3V8wDttUsbBydCaahV1agAegeoImBxAAs4BwIF6HWliD3AA+t0OygCjRMQA)

Comment: that's what i'm looking for. thank you!

Comment: but why that doesn't work on multiple items array like in this [playground link](https://shorturl.at/eBQ03)?